# Removing a route to block access to a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, rails-routing

There were some controllers in my application which weren't secure enough to deploy to the public -- ie. the authentication mechanisms weren't ready.

As a means to block the controllers quickly, I removed the routes for them. Now, no route leads to them.

**Is removing its route an efficient way to block access to a controller?**

In other words, is there another way for a malicious user to get to a controller if the route for it has been disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you should also check if there are any kind of catch-all routes in your routes file, examples of this would be:

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
```

If you don't have anything like this, you are probably safe now.

Comment: Generally if something is not routed it is not accessible. As pointed out here, sometimes things are routed by default.

Comment: OK, but, let's be perfectly clear about this:  if it is not in the output of `rake routes`, then there is no route to that resource, correct?  Even the catch-all should show up there.

Comment: Yes, but the catch all won't show your controller name, it will just show just like it is above. So you might want to find any route that matches on these **:controller** or **:action** variables, these would also be the dangerous ones.